# webdev.webserver.exe has encountered a problem

Tags: asp.net, webserver

i am facing an error "webdev.webserver.exe has encountered a problem" in only one project all other projects are executing/debugging properly.after showing this alert window i do not able to debug my application. after closing and reopening the project is debugged properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this re-occuring frequently?

I occasionally get this and also "unable to attach debugger" for what seems like no reason. Although this seems less prevailaint in VS 2008 than 05.

Am I right in saying your using webdev express? Maybe update to latest version.

Sorry I cant be more specific.